# Modifying an enqueued script URL

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

There is a following code in one of the installed plugins:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-recaptcha',
    add_query_arg(
        array(
            'render' => $service->get_sitekey(),
        ),
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'
    ),
    array(),
    '3.0',
    true
);
```

This code produces the following URL for script downloading:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<sitekey>&ver=3.0
```

I need to inject a locale component into this URL to make it look like

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<locale>&render=<sitekey>&ver=3.0
```

I'm already wrote a function to get required locale part, but I don't know how to modify an URL for enqueued script (of course I don't want to touch the plugin source code). The only thing came to my mind is to look at the `wp_scripts` object and somehow modify it before the scripts enqueue task take place. Is there a better way to do this? Some hook I'm not aware of or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`script_loader_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_src/) function to filter the URLs of scripts before they are output in a `<script>` tag. I'd suggest something like this:

```
add_filter(
    'script_loader_src',
    function( $src, $handle ) {
        // Only filter the specific script we want.
        if ( 'google-recaptcha' === $handle ) {
            // Add the argument to the exisitng URL.
            $src = add_query_arg( 'hl', '<locale>', $src );
        }

        // Return the filtered URL.
        return $src;
    },
    10, // Default priority.
    2 // IMPORTANT. Needs to match the number of accepted arguments.
);
```

Just replace `'<locale>'` with whichever locale you need, or a variable containing it.